# Ordering time-stamped date in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am struggling to find a good way to organise my state in Redux with React. It is a simple Blog with posts. I am getting an array from the api that is already ordered from oldest to newest. Since the app is a bit more complicated, I'd like to store the state in an object with the uuid as keys, so I can access it easily.

```
{ 
    uuid_post1: { ...post1 },
    uuid_post2: { ...post2 },
    ...
}
```

With the format above it is easy for me to sync the state between API and React without refetching data all the time. But I do need to display the output in an ordered form from newest to oldest.

Is there an easy way to solve this and keep the date info in the object? Is there another good way to organise state for this use case?

Thanks.

Comment: you could convert your state to an array and use array.sort before displaying https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reducer you'll want to index the posts by ID and also save the sorted IDs. This will let you look up the posts efficiently, and also maintain a list of them in the order that you received them (oldest to newest). You can get them in the reverse order using a selector.

```js
switch (action.type) {
    case 'POSTS_RECEIVED':
        return {
            ...state,
            orderedPostIDs: posts.map(p => p.id),
            postsById: posts.reduce((acc, post) => {
                acc[post.id] = post;
            }, {});
    }
}
```

With this `orderedPostIDs` is an array of Post IDs and `postsById` is an object where the keys are Post IDs and the values are the posts.

```js
function getPostByID(state, postId) {
  return state.posts.postsById[id];
}

// Should use reselect here because it's returning a new array with every call
// oldest to newest - post are received from API in this order
function getPostsSortedByDateAscending(state) {
    return state.posts.orderedPostIDs.map(id => getPostByID(state, id));
}

// Should use reselect here because it's returning a new array with every call
// newest to oldest
function getPostsSortedByDateDescending(state) {
    // copy to new array, because Array.reverse mutates the value
    return [].concat(getPostsSortedByDateAscending(state)).reverse();
}
```

---

Another approach which makes your state simpler is to only store `postsById`, as [Max commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099804/ordering-time-stamped-date-in-react-redux/60100051#comment106296540_60100051). To get the sorted posts, you'll use Object.values() and then sort them as needed.

```js
// oldest to newest - need to use reselect here
function getPostsSortedByDateAscending(state) {
    return _.sortBy(Object.values(state.posts.postsById), p => p.date)
}

// oldest to newest - need to use reselect here
function getPostsSortedByDateDescending(state) {
    // copy to new array, because Array.reverse mutates the value
    return [].concat(getPostsSortedByDateAscending(state)).reverse();
}
```

Comment: I don‘t really see how this would preserve the ordering from newest to oldest

Comment: You said the array of posts is already sorted, if you want to access them you can use the posts array

Comment: Lodash (its already in the bundle for my app) also comes with the .mapkey and .omit function that I am using for the mapping.

Comment: Just tweaked my answer to remove the unnecessary cases for this question (and removed duplication of data in there)

Comment: Just noticed that you wanted them sorted newest to oldest as well - updated my answer

Comment: If you are using reselect then you might as well avoid storing `orderedPostIDs` in redux. Order almost always depends on the component that's consuming items (one component wants posts sorted by date asc, another by date desc, and another by amount of likes, etc.). Keeping `orderedPostIDs` not only doesn't make sense in this scenario but also can introduce bugs if, e.g. someone updates `postsById` without updating `orderedPostIDs`, or just wants to merge a new bunch of posts into existing array without overwriting

Comment: good points - keeping only an index of the posts makes updating the state a lot easier